# Counting rate correction for Poisson process

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, statistics

Let's consider an experimental setup in which I have to count events from a **Poisson process**.

In my case, I am counting single photons with a Hamamatsu photomultiplier tube (PMT).
If a photon impinges on my detector, I measure a voltage spike at the output.

If my detector were ideal, that is if its response time were zero, every time a photon arrives I have a voltage pulse and I count all photons.

Unfortunately, the response time of my system is not zero, but rather a given value thet we call $\delta t$.

If a photon impinges at a time $t_0$ and a second photon within the time window $t_0\le t \le t_0 + \delta t$, I miss it because the system is still "blinded" by the first photon.

[image: Scheme of the experiment]

I am trying to figure out how to estimate the number of missed photons due to the response time $\delta t$, in order to correct the rate of photons that I measure for this effect.

The Hamamatsu PMT handbook (that can be found at [this link](https://www.hamamatsu.com/content/dam/hamamatsu-photonics/sites/documents/99_SALES_LIBRARY/etd/PMT_handbook_v3aE.pdf)) in chapter 6, section 3c (page 145 for your convenience) explains that you can estimate the number of missed photons in the following way.

> Assuming that the true rate of photons is $N$ (units of counts per unit time), the measured rate is $M$ (also units of counts per unit time), and the time interval in which the sensor is blind after a successful detection is $\delta t$, we can compute the dead time of the detector per unit time as $T_{dead} = M\cdot \delta t$. From this we can compute the number of missed points per unit time (*loss counts rate*) $N-M$ as
> \begin{equation}
> N-M = N \cdot T_{dead} = N\cdot M\cdot \delta t
> \end{equation}
> From this equation, it is possible to recover the true photon rate as
> \begin{equation}
> N = \frac{M}{1-M\cdot \delta t}
> \end{equation}

This calculation although reasonable, in my opinion, assumes that the inter-arrival times $\Delta T_i$ of the photons, that is the time that passes between a photon arriving on the detector and the subsequent, are *uniformly distributed*.

However, the detection of photons is generally considered a **Poisson process**, hence the inter-arrival times are *exponentially distributed*.
\begin{equation}
\Delta T_i \sim N e^{-N \cdot t},
\end{equation}
where once again $N$ is the true rate of photons.
The exponential distribution tells us that small inter-arrival are more likely than long inter-arrival times. This makes it so that in the time window $\delta t$ where the detector is still blind from the previous pulse statistically it is more likely to have a second photon compared to a time window of the same length at later times.

---

My attempted correction to the loss counts rate formula if the inter-arrival times of the photons are exponentially distributed would be
\begin{equation}
N-M = N\cdot M\cdot \delta t \frac{N\delta_t}{1-e^{-N\delta t}} \quad \xrightarrow[]{\quad N\to \,0\quad}\quad N\cdot M\cdot \delta t
\end{equation}

In the limit of the rate $N$ going to zero, the exponential distribution becomes a uniform distribution and I recover the previous formula (as expected)

I came up with this formula as intuition and I am not sure if it is right. I wanted to check with the community if it is right.

A quick simulation seems to hint that the formula is correct, as you can see in the plot below ($\delta t = 100\,n\mbox{s}$).

[image: Simulation result]

Comment: Does the output pulse amplitude not increase when multiple photons are detected?

Comment: @ThePhoton apparently the peak height in such a system can vary a lot even if single photons with all same energy are absorbed due to the statistics of photoelectron emission in a PMT. The peak height that we detect vary a lot, but they are well separated and follow a Poisson statistics, so I think that each peak is a single photon detection.

Comment: You might want to look into the lore and literature of pulse-pileup in nuclear physics measurements.

Comment: @JonCuster do you have some references to suggest? The book by Knoll?

Comment: The book by Knoll, or the equivalent book by Leo. You write about pile up, in which case you would get a larger pulse amplitude. This is different from dead time. Unless you saturate the current in your PMT (bright light, also, danger of damaging the photocathode), your PMT has no dead time, just pile up. Your plot looks reasonable, but if you operate in the regime where the difference matters, consider to measure current instead of counting photons.